# Replace string and create a new string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a string :

```
htmlString = [newstemp desc];
NSString * newstring;
newstring = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/r/n" withString:@" "];
NSLog(@"%@",newstring);

<p>DEDUCCI&Oacute;N CIEGA BREVES LABORALES CORRECCI&Oacute;N PRIMA DE RIESGO IMSS VENTA BIEN MUEBLE IEPS MILLONARIOS CAPITALIZACI&Oacute;N DELGADA</p>\r\n\r\n<p>DEDUCCI&Oacute;N CIEGA BREVES LABORALES CORRECCI&Oacute;N PRIMA DE RIESGO IMSS VENTA BIEN MUEBLE IEPS MILLONARIOS CAPITALIZACI&Oacute;N DELGADA</p>\r\n
```

I want to remove special characters \r\n

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *old = @"DEDUCCIÓN CIEGA BREVES LABORALES CORRECCIÓN PRIMA DE RIESGO IMSS VENTA BIEN MUEBLE IEPS MILLONARIOS CAPITALIZACIÓN DELGADA \r\n\r\n";

NSString *new = [old stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\\r" withString:@""];
new = [new stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\\n" withString:@""];
```

Comment: Worked, Code work's perfectly thanks allot...

Comment: Why do this into two steps when you can do it with one?